# In libreCalc how do you change who the file is created by?

Tags: libreoffice

Ok I know this isn't exactly a linux question, but does anyone know how to change who created the file. In microsoft excel it's prepare but there doesn't seem to be an actual way to edit it that I've been able to find and I'm sure my instructor won't like the default name it is using to be acceptable for much longer no matter what the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In File->Properties you have the option to Apply or Reset User data, which you can edit under Tools->Options.